# Prove that the Stone-Cech compactification of a discrete space is such that the closure of every open set is open

Tags: general-topology, continuity, compactification

Let $X$ be a discrete space and $\beta (X)$ its Stone-Cech compactification. We have to prove that for every open set $U$ of $\beta (X)$, $\overline{U}$ is open in $\beta (X)$.
So far the only idea I have is to use the extension of some continuous function from $X$ into the discrete space $\{0,1\}$ but I'm not sure how to use it in this case. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I literally wrote that I have to prove that in the stone cech compactification of a discrete space the closure of an open set is open

Comment: @CrSb0001 Again, try not to use stock messages without checking whether or not they apply : ) (no harm done)